# Stripe elements: how can I validate a card element is not blank client-side?

Tags: javascript, validation, stripe-payments

Stripe recommends using the `change` event for client side validation of the `card` element:

```
cardElement.on('change', function(event) {
  if (event.complete) {
    // enable payment button
  } else if (event.error) {
    // show validation to customer
  }
});
```

However this approach makes it impossible to determine a card element is invalid if the user never edits / changes it. I can always try to submit the payment with `confirmCardPayment` but that is inefficient—this validation should be possible client-side.

I can work around this by having the payment form default to an error state that is then resolved (or not) the first time the user changes the card. However this is not convenient as it would require me to internationalize the "Your card number is incomplete" error message in my application code versus relying on Stripe to this.

Ideally I would be able to either synchronously check the card element for an error or at least synchronously trigger the change event but neither of these seem possible.

Comment: there is more events like 'ready' or 'click' , the stripe accepts it

Comment: @MohamedGhoneim `click` does not help because what if the user never clicks? `ready` would work but that event doesn't provide any error information.

Answer (score 8):

Stripe.js applies several classes to every Stripe Element's container based on the state of the Element:

- `StripeElement--complete`
- `StripeElement--empty`
- `StripeElement--focus`
- `StripeElement--invalid`
- `StripeElement--webkit-autofill` (Chrome and Safari only)

You can read more about these classes, including how to customize them, in [Stripe's documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/the_element_container).

It sounds like checking for the `StripeElement--empty` class might suffice for your use case.  You can do something like this:

```js
const cardElementContainer = document.querySelector('#card-element');

let cardElementEmpty = cardElementContainer.classList.contains('StripeElement--empty');

// Do things based on cardElementEmpty being true or false
```

Comment: This is helpful thank you! However it is not the ideal solution as this interface does not give me the appropriate internationalized error message in the same way that the `change` event’s `error` object does. But maybe there is no way to get this.

Comment: Usually you would call a method that uses the Stripe Element (like `stripe.confirmCardPayment`) and, if the Element is empty, you'll get the `error` there you can handle in a similar way to the `change` event error.  Will that approach not work for your use case?

Comment: I believe for `confirmCardPayment` you need to have a valid `PaymentIntent` to submit whereas I would like to validate the card before setting up the `PaymentIntent` in the first place.

Comment: Did you solved this somehow?

Comment: The `StripeElement--invalid` class will tell you if the content of the Element is invalid or not.  Does that work for you @exSnake?

Comment: Hi, i noticed the change in class when editing stripe fields, but if stripe has a method to validate before submitting that would be better. A user can always nanipulate classes using dev tools.

Comment: A user can manipulate your client-side JavaScript too, so not sure why doing that vs. using the classes would be better?  You can access the classes on the element from JavaScript using `classList`.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been looking to validate my elements without payment intent. Looks like stripe has this for exactly that.

`elements.submit()`

Look it up here https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements/submit