# In React, validate CardElement is not blank client-side with useRef()

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, use-ref

We are using  to accept payment info as part of a signup form, and for the form, would like to know whether or not the  is complete. The solution here - [Stripe elements: how can I validate a card element is not blank client-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862556/stripe-elements-how-can-i-validate-a-card-element-is-not-blank-client-side) - uses `document.querySelector()` rather than the useRef() hook.

CardElement with surrounding container for styles

```
const OurCardElement = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <OurElementContainer>
            <CardElement
                ref={ref}
                isDisabled={true}
                options={cardElementOpts}
            />
        </CardElementContainer>
    );
});
```

Our signup page looks something like this:

```
const SignupPage = () => {
    // hooks
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    const cardElementRef = useRef();

    // want the card state here (this isn't working)
    let isCardComplete = ref.current.className.includes('StripeElement--complete')            

    // signup handler
    const handleSignup = async (e) => {
        const cardElement = elements.getElement('card');
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            // subscribe
            cardElement.update({ disabled: true });
            const paymentMethodReq = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: 'card',
                card: cardElement
            });

            // Handle Creating Payment Subscription
            let paymentObject = {
                id,
                paymentMethod: paymentMethodReq.paymentMethod.id
            };
            const stripeResponse = await Axios.post(`${apiBaseUrl}/stripe/new_payment_subscriptions`, paymentObject);

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    // Return
    return (
        ... rest of signup form (name, email, password, etc.)
        <OurCardElement ref={cardElementRef} /> // submit payment info
        <button 
            onClick={() => handleSignup}
            isDisabled={!isCardComplete}
        />
    );
});
```

We have a form (not shown) for name, email, password, a  for submitting credit card info, a submit button, and a handler function for handling submit, which creates the user in our database (not shown) and sets up the stripe payment as well.

It would appear that we cannot attach the `ref` to the `<CardElement>` container. We receive the error `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`

We are trying this approach because, as mentioned in [Stripe elements: how can I validate a card element is not blank client-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65862556/stripe-elements-how-can-i-validate-a-card-element-is-not-blank-client-side) , we can use the className of the card element to identify if the card element is empty / complete / etc. How can we otherwise use `useRef()` to get the class from the card element for this? Or is there another way, not using either `useRef()` or `document.querySelector()` to grab the className, that we can use to identify if the card element is accurately filled in?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't instead listen for the `change` [event](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_change?type=cardElement), which returns a `complete` boolean?

Comment: CardElement is not a DOM element, you can't pass ref to it unless itself uses ForwardRef.